# Python Fastapi "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" Error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, mysql-python

This is my database.py

```py
from models import create_engine,sessionmaker
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as declarative
from pymysql.constants.CLIENT import MULTI_STATEMENTS
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
# from dotenv.
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql://fastapi:fastapipassword@localhost/skillhub"

engine  = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,connect_args={"client_flag":MULTI_STATEMENTS})

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True,bind=engine)
Base = declarative.declarative_base()
SessionNow = scoped_session(SessionLocal)

#This is the function I use to get session
def get_db():
    db = _database.SessionNow()
    try:
        return db
    finally:
         db.close()
        pass
```

Whenever I hit this endpoint, it keeps giving me the following error.

routes.py

```py
@app.get('/api/get/vacancy')
def get_vacancys():
    return _services.get_all_vacancys()
#services.py
#The function that is called above in my services.py file 
def get_all_vacancys(db= get_db()):
    db_data = db.query(_models.Vacancy).all()
    all_vacancy_data = []
    for data in db_data:
        offi.append(_schemas.VacancyReturn.from_orm(data))
        print(len(offi))
    return all_vacancy_data
```

**The Error:**

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:35162 - "GET /api/get/vacancy/73862a9d-4eeb-428f-93bd-bebbfd617ef2 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xeb/Code/Python/fastapivenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/xeb/Code/Python/fastapivenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/xeb/Code/Python/fastapivenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 183, in execute
    while self.nextset():
  File "/home/xeb/Code/Python/fastapivenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 137, in nextset
    nr = db.next_result()
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
[SQL: SELECT vacancy.id AS vacancy_id, vacancy.name_of_vacancy AS vacancy_name_of_vacancy, vacancy.pick_id AS vacancy_pick_id, vacancy.location_of_company AS vacancy_location_of_company, vacancy.post_type AS vacancy_post_type, vacancy.vacancy_type AS vacancy_vacancy_type, vacancy.name_of_organization AS vacancy_name_of_organization, vacancy.description AS vacancy_description, vacancy.email_of_office AS vacancy_email_of_office, vacancy.number_of_office AS vacancy_number_of_office, vacancy.posted_by AS vacancy_posted_by, vacancy.logo_url_of_company AS vacancy_logo_url_of_company, vacancy.salary_proposed AS vacancy_salary_proposed, vacancy.experience_required AS vacancy_experience_required, vacancy.education_required AS vacancy_education_required, vacancy.other_qualification AS vacancy_other_qualification 
FROM vacancy 
WHERE vacancy.pick_id = %s 
 LIMIT %s]
[parameters: ('73862a9d-4eeb-428f-93bd-bebbfd617ef2', 1)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

The error is seemingly random as it happens once in every few attempts to hit the endpoint.
I did some research and this is seemingly a mysql error rather than a fastapi or sqlalchemy error, I've looked at some previous questions asked about this issue it was not helpful, This has not happened when previously using the same application.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Cross-posted and answered on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8413).